# Extract BigQuery partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to extract the complete BigQuery partitioned table with one command so that data of each partition is extracted into a separate folder of the format part_col=date_yyyy-mm-dd

Since Bigquery partitioned table can read files from the hive type partitioned directories, is there a way to extract the data in a similar way. I can extract each partition separately, however that is very cumbersome when i an extracting a lot of partitions

Comment: seems like a feature request for the issue tracker

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this programmatically. For instance, you can [export partitioned data by using the partition decorator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-table-data#exporting_table_data) such as table$20190801. And then on the bq extract command you can use [URI Patterns](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_into_one_or_more_files) (look the example of the workers pattern) for the GCS objects.

Since all objects will be within the same bucket, the folders are just [an hierarchical illusion](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork), so you can specify URI patterns on the folders as well, but not on the bucket.

So you would do a script where you loop over the DATE value, with something like:

```
bq extract 
--destination_format [CSV, NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON, AVRO] 
--compression [GZIP, AVRO supports DEFLATE and SNAPPY] 
--field_delimiter [DELIMITER] 
--print_header [true, false] 
[PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE]$[DATE]
gs://[BUCKET]/part_col=[DATE]/[FILENAME]-*.[csv, json, avro]
```

You can't do it automatically with just a bq command. For this it would be better to [raise a feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) as suggested by Felipe.

Comment: Thanks Neri, I have implemented this programmatially but i was just curious if we could do it using a single command. As confirmed by you and Felipe that such a feature does not exist, will raise a feature request

Comment: Hi when I run this bq extract --destination_format=CSV test_dataset.test_partitiontime$20210716  gs://testbucket/ part_col=20210716/test.csv, I get this output ` Not found: Table test-
net:temp.test_partitiontime0210716 was not found in location EU `. My table is partitioned by date, do you think what could be the problem? ps: normally I have 7k rows for 2021-07-16 date –

Comment: Hi emily, try escaping the $ with backslash, you are probably using a bash shell and the $2 is being treated as a variable that is replaced by blank value

Comment: Can someone please share the script if they have on exporting the bigquery dataset based on the type of table.

Answer (score 0):

Set the project as `test_dataset` using `gcloud init` before running the below command.

`bq extract --destination_format=CSV 'test_partitiontime$20210716' gs://testbucket/20210716/test*.csv`

This will create a folder with the name `20210716` inside `testbucket` and write the file there.